# how MFC app catches this WM_SETTINGCHANGE

Tags: c++, mfc, callback

I create MFC dialog apps, but I don't know how to catch messages sent from OS like this message WM_SETTINGCHANGE.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with class view, right click on your main window class and select Properties. In the "Messages" section of the Properties window find WM_SETTINGCHANGE and click it to add a message handler function in your class.

Comment: Since this question doesn't specify a particular IDE, you should expand your answer to include a solution that works with Visual Studio .NET 2002, 2003, 2005, and 2008 as well.

Comment: thanks ScottMcP-MVP.  I will try that out tomorrow and will let you know.